# Android : About opening zip or rar files by other app

Tags: permissions, fileprovider

I implement this target by below code

open file:

```
/* 打开文件
* @param file
*/
public static void openFile(Activity context, File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    //设置intent的Action属性
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    //获取文件file的Uri
    Uri uri = UriUtils.file2Uri(file);
    //获取文件file的MIME类型
    String type = getMimeType(context, uri);
    //设置intent的data和Type属性。
    intent.setDataAndType(/*uri*/uri, type);
    try {
        //跳转
        context.startActivity(intent); //这里最好try一下，有可能会报错。 //比如说你的MIME类型是打开邮箱，但是你手机里面没装邮箱客户端，就会报错。
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    //String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    String type = cR.getType(uri);
    return type;
}
```

file to uri

```
 /**
 * File to uri.
 *
 * @param file The file.
 * @return uri
 */
public static Uri file2Uri(@NonNull final File file) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        String authority = Utils.getApp().getPackageName() + ".utilcode.provider";
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(Utils.getApp(), authority, file);
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
}
```

provider declare

```
     <provider
        android:name="com.blankj.utilcode.util.UtilsFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.utilcode.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/util_code_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

provider resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <root-path
    name="root_path"
    path="" />

  <files-path
    name="files_path"
    path="." />

  <cache-path
    name="cache_path"
    path="." />

  <external-path
    name="external_path"
    path="." />

  <external-files-path
    name="external_files_path"
    path="." />

  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache_path"
    path="." />

  <external-media-path
    name="external_media_path"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

Now I have a question: I can open zip or rar files by choosing qq browser, but not by choosing quark or uc browser

How I can do to open zip or rar files by choosing quark or uc browser.
Thanks for your time first.

By the way, I can open normal format file such as jpeg or txt by choosing any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

Not like qq browser, uc browser won't copy stream to itself storage, it will ignore an uri of zip what can't bring its source path.So I handle zip or rar file by transing operation as follows:

1.forbid scoped storage

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
</application>
```

2.transfer uri to other uri that can be used to get real path from MediaStore

```
/**
 * 获取可以拿到真实路径的uri
 */
public static Uri getCompressedFileUri(Context context, File compressedFile) {
    Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    String filePath = compressedFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            externalUri,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?",
            new String[]{filePath}, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID);
            if (idIndex > -1) {
                int contentId = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
                return Uri.withAppendedPath(externalUri, "" + contentId);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            if (compressedFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(externalUri, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

3.modify open file code

```
/* 打开文件
 * @param file
 */
public static void openFile(Activity context, File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    //设置intent的Action属性
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    //获取文件file的Uri
    Uri uri = UriUtils.file2Uri(file);
    //获取文件file的MIME类型
    String type = getMimeType(context, uri);
    //设置最终Uri
    Uri finalUri;
    String fileNameLower = file.getName().toLowerCase();
    if (fileNameLower.endsWith(".zip") || fileNameLower.endsWith(".rar")) {
        /**
         * content://${applicationId}.utilcode.provider/external_files_path/Download/source_files/466671029D7480FCB2BB69B0976206CD_6371ebd8c95f6.zip
         * 转为
         * content://media/external/file/504
         * 压缩包需要特殊处理，有些第三方app是直接在原始路径上读取流的，不得不返回可以查询路径的uri
         */
        finalUri = getCompressedFileUri(context, file);
    } else {
        /**
         * content://${applicationId}.utilcode.provider/external_files_path/Download/source_files/66E27CA36A252A7C8F53BC2DD0E67084_637adc0f0666b.png
         * 其他格式如果也封装成可以获取原始路径的uri，可能无法被系统app识别，他可能就直接先识别后缀名发现有误，就失败了
         */
        finalUri = uri;
    }
    //设置intent的data和Type属性。
    intent.setDataAndType(/*uri*/finalUri, type);
    try {
        //跳转
        context.startActivity(intent); //这里最好try一下，有可能会报错。 //比如说你的MIME类型是打开邮箱，但是你手机里面没装邮箱客户端，就会报错。
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

refer following links:

https://blog.csdn.net/qq_40716795/article/details/127738057
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_36707431/article/details/118335407

Answer (score 0):

Today tester show me the failure of opening zip by uc browser in Android 11.
Immediately I notice that app can't forbid scoped storage, but can access public storage such as Download directory without permission in Android 11.So I save files in Download directory, and then it works in Android 11 finally.
Here's the code

Download/appPackage/files

```
new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), AppUtils.getAppPackageName()), "files")
```